# android Tasks and BackStack

Tags: android, task

Suppose there are 3 Tasks. Task A, Task B, Task C.
Are there 3 BackStacks for these 3 Tasks (or) only 1 BackStack for all the 3 Tasks??
How Task is associated with the Backstack??

Comment: Yes. Definitely each task has its own backstack. Therefore there are 3 backstacks for these 3 tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html):

> A task is a collection of activities that users interact with when performing a certain job. The activities are arranged in a stack (the "back stack"), in the order in which each activity is opened.

Hence...

> Suppose there are 3 Tasks. Task A, Task B, Task C. Are there 3 BackStacks for these 3 Tasks (or) only 1 BackStack for all the 3 Tasks?

There is one back stack per task.

Answer (score -1):

Everything with regard to Tasks and Back stacks in Android, including your question, can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html.

The images and text are quite self-explanatory.